# How to get final query from Cassandra Cql?

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm using Cassandra c# driver 2.5 and its IMapper for querying Cassandra database.

**Problem:** 
For same query arguments, I get two different outputs. I can't seem to find the way to see what is the final cql query generated.

It's probably a dumb question, but where can I find it?

**EDIT:**

```
        Guid userId = ...;
        string statistic = ...;
        int limit = ...;

        var cql = Cql.New(" WHERE id=? AND period_type=? AND statistic=? LIMIT ?",
                                      userId,
                                      (int)PeriodType.Daily,
                                      statistic,
                                      limit);

        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(_session);

        var statistics = mapper.Fetch<Statistic>(cql);

        // Here 'statistics' hold 1 entry, where a select query in cqlsh using same arguments as above returns 2 entries.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your query code?